# Will disk brakes fit on the Apollo Verge

Tags: mountain-bike

I am wondering will disk brakes fit my bike, the Apollo Verge men's mountain bike?

Comment: The images I can find don't appear to show brake bosses.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se]! I removed the photo because it a) didn't show the parts of the bike it needed to, and b) 2/3 of the image needed cropping. You can undo my changes if you wish, but I really recommend that you take a new picture from the rear of the bike, showing the wheel clearances on both sides and the backstays. More than one pic would be better.

Comment: Search the World Wide Web for mountain bikes with disc brakes and look at the pictures of the brake calipers. Look at how and where they attach to the frame. Does your bike have any semblance of mounts like the ones you are seeing? If you have mounts on the fork and near the rear triangle chances are you can mount calipers.  If you're bike doesn't already have disc brakes I'm guessing it can't accommodate them without heavy modification costing more than the bike itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the pictures I was able to find online, the [Apollo Verge](http://www.halfords.com/cycling/bikes/mountain-bikes/apollo-verge-mens-mountain-bike) I agree with the commenters that it does not appear to have mounting holes for disc brakes.  It has a couple holes on the rear above the dropout where the stays meet, but those appear to be for fenders and a rack. They cannot be used for mounting disk brakes. The fork does not appear to have any kind of mounts for disk brakes.  The hubs of your wheels also require mounting holes for the disk.  It's hard to tell from the pictures, but it appears the hubs don't have mounting holes, and I can't imagine that they would be present on a bike of this quality that didn't come with disk brakes to begin with.

Finally, the Apollo Verge appears to be a very low end department store bike. It's probably not worth the money you would put into it to convert over to disk brakes, even for just the front as you would have to get a new fork and wheel/hub.  If you are unhappy with your braking performance, the first thing you should do is make sure everything is adjusted properly.  After that, if you are still unhappy, consider upgrading to a higher quality v-brakes. The equipment that comes on low end department store bikes is often of extremely low quality and often cannot be made to work well no matter how well it is adjusted.   Even [a lower end, but still decent](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/shimano-alivio-t4000-v-brake/rp-prod119943) set of brakes will probably cost you close to $40, or £30, which is about a third of the current price of the bike.